# Using Variables for BETWEEN clause of SQL in Powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I have written powershell script to query SQL database and export the result to csv file. I need to export the data between two dates. Like in below code WHERE and BETWEEN are expected to take starttime and endtime as variables. But its not working. If i replace starttime and endtime variable with time like '2023-05-01', it works well. Can somebody pls help me to solve this ?

```
$starttime = '2023-05-01'
$endtime = '2023-05-10'

$SQLServer = "HostName"
$SQLDBName = "Historian"
$uid = "sa"
$pwd = ""

$SqlQuery = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(mi,$GMTOffset,EventDate),103) As DATE, 
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(mi,$GMTOffset,EventDate),114) As TIME,
                    FROM [Historian].[dbo].[S2KEventReport_View] 

**WHERE (DATEADD(mi,330,EventDate) BETWEEN $starttime AND $endtime)"**

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True;"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$Dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$DataSet.Tables[0] | export-csv -Path $EventExportPath -NoTypeInformation
$filenameFormat = (Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy_HH.mm.ss_") + " "+ "S2KEvents.csv"
Rename-Item -Path $EventExportPath -NewName $filenameFormat
```

i expect sql query in powershell to execute and return the result as it runs in VS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literal [dates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?#supported-string-literal-formats-for-date) in T-SQL queries are expressed as *strings* and must therefore be enclosed in `'...'`.

Therefore, you must include these quotes in your [expandable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) PowerShell string (`"..."`):

```bash
# Note the '...' around $starttime and $endtime
$SqlQuery = 
  "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(mi,$GMTOffset,EventDate),103) As DATE, 
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(mi,$GMTOffset,EventDate),114) As TIME,
   FROM   [Historian].[dbo].[S2KEventReport_View] 
   WHERE  (DATEADD(mi,330,EventDate) BETWEEN '$starttime' AND '$endtime')"
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mklement0 https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0. Your reply has helped me in solving my problem. Thank you !!